# Rails `NOT IN (null)` returning no results

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to retrieve some records and having an issue when one of my parameters is an empty array. I understand why the query isn't returning any results, but I don't know the best way of handling it within rails. In my code, I'm calling

```
@user.trustees.where(["trustees.default = true AND trustees.id NOT IN (?)", trustees.map{ |t| t.id }])
```

This works as expected when the trustees array actually contains objects, however when it doesn't, the query returns nothing, as the SQL produced results in

```
SELECT `users`.* 
FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `trustees` ON `users`.`id` = `trustees`.`trustee_id` 
WHERE `trustees`.`truster_id` = 1 
AND (trustees.default = true 
AND trustees.id NOT IN (NULL))
```

What's the easiest way of avoiding the `NOT IN (NULL)` issue that I'm having?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
@user.trustees.where(default: true).where.not(id: trustees.map{ |t| t.id })
```

Comment: Perfect! I'd gone with `@user.trustees.where(["trustees.default = true AND (trustees.id NOT IN (:trustees) OR :trustees IS NULL)", { trustees: trustees.map(&:id) }])` but this is MUCH cleaner. Cheers :D

Comment: @PaReeOhNos: That is the advantage of using the correct rails version tags on SO :)

Comment: Agreed. Always annoying when the wrong tags are used and then the user complains that it doesn't work on the version they're using :P

Answer (score 1):

For better performance use following

```
@user.trustees.where(default: true).where.not(id: trustees.pluck(:id))
```

using **pluck** instead of **map** substantially reduced load time from 90ms to 3ms in a similar query i'm using.